# Is it possible to copy html element and an element canvas together?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have red rectangle as a canvas.

And i have green rectangle as a html element.

I try to unite them together as a one canvas element as you can see in the demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/ThZKR/)

My code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
    #myCanvas{
  width:300px; height:150px;
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
  position:absolute; top:0;left:0;
}
div{
  width:75px; height:75px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  position:absolute; top:0;left:50px;
  background-color:green;
}
button{
   position:absolute; top:0;left:150px;

}
  </style>
  </head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" >
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <div></div>

<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(10,10,50,50);

function copy()
{
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(10,10,50,50);
ctx.putImageData(imgData,10,70);
}
</script>

<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>

</body>
</html>
```

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to get html element as image and then you can easily put it into canvas. But maybe you can make it by taking screenshot of html.

You might want to look at this article;

[Take screenshot of web page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/)